# Get full and correct path from registry value via batch file

Tags: batch-file, msbuild

I need help in getting full and correct folder path from registry value via batch file.
I have such a code to do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set R_MSBUILD_KEY="\\.\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\12.0"
set R_MSBUILD_VALUE="MSBuildToolsPath"

REM Get MSBUILD path from registry
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%A IN ('REG QUERY %R_MSBUILD_KEY% /v %R_MSBUILD_VALUE% 2^>nul') DO SET MSBUILD_PATH=%%C%%D

if defined MSBUILD_PATH (
    @ECHO MSBUILD = %MSBUILD_PATH%\MSBuild.exe
) else (
    @echo %R_MSBUILD_KEY%\%R_MSBUILD_VALUE% not found.
)
```

As a response I receive the following path:

```
MSBUILD = C:\ProgramFiles\MSBuild.exe
```

Instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe`.

My problem is that I cannot understand how to retrieve full and correct path(with spaces in folders where it is actually).How to receive full and correct path in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the reg query output I can't be sure, but see if this line gives you the correct output.

```
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY %R_MSBUILD_KEY% /v %R_MSBUILD_VALUE% 2^>nul') DO SET "MSBUILD_PATH=%%C"
```

Comment: You can use any other key/value where is using path to something throughout 'Program Files'.